# How can I retrieve files within a repo in Azure within a Powershell script?

Tags: azure, powershell

I need to (within a Powershell script) determine all the possible controller file names within a repository.   This is for a test that will hit every controller and verify it is functioning and not missing from the startup file. (MVC app)

Since all the files are DLLs I cannot simply ask for the files in the folder nor do I want to hard code the names.   How can I get a listing of files within a certain folder in order call each one to test within a powershell script?

Perhaps a better way to ask this is:
How can I list files within a folder that is inside a repo? (using a Powershell script)

Comment: You run the powershell script from local? and the .dll is in azure -> kudu site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could refer to this doc:[Interacting with Azure Web Apps Virtual File System using PowerShell and the Kudu API](https://blog.kloud.com.au/2016/08/30/interacting-with-azure-web-apps-virtual-file-system-using-powershell-and-the-kudu-api/). It uses the `VFS API` in the [wiki doc](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/REST-API#vfs). And there is a api to list files at directory specified by path.

```
GET /api/vfs/{path}/
Lists files at directory specified by path.
```

And in the previous doc, under the title **Downloading a File from an App Service**, there is a scripts to download the files. I use the path without `$kuduPath` to list files. And you need to **Getting the Kudu REST API Authorisation header via PowerShell**. And then the scripts would be like this.

```
$kuduApiUrl="https://<webname>.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/site/wwwroot/"
 Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $kuduApiUrl `
 -Headers @{"Authorization"=$kuduApiAuthorisationToken;"If-Match"="*"} `
 -Method GET `
 -OutFile $localPath `
 -ContentType "multipart/form-data"
```

And here is the result pic.It will list all files and the folders.

[image]

hope this could help you, if you still have other questions,please let me know.

Comment: I will have to try Kudu.   Currently I am testing with Swagger to get a json file with the controller names I need to test with.  I was going to get a file listing from the build process, copy that file into the artifacts and read in during the release process for the testing.